# how to let another future poll when a long poll request is blocking in a poll fn

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future

For some reason, I must use tokio/future 0.1 in my project and I want to watch a lot of consul service. I want other same future can be poll when a future is blocking by a long poll request. how do I do?

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
tokio = "0.1"
futures= "0.1"
```

my test case will output this is a test xxx every 5s

```
this is a test name1
this is a test name2
this is a test name1
this is a test name2
```

```
use std::thread;
use std::thread::sleep;

use futures::{Async, Future, Stream, task};
use futures::future::join_all;
use tokio::runtime::current_thread;



pub struct JnsWatcher {
    name: String,
}

impl JnsWatcher {
    pub fn new(name: String) -> Self {
        JnsWatcher {
            name
        }
    }
}


impl Future for JnsWatcher {
    type Item = ();
    type Error = ();

    fn poll(&mut self, ) -> Result<Async<Self::Item>, Self::Error> {
        loop {
            // as speedy says, it will be an non-block call ,
            // and then it will be reqwest::get(path).await; but poll is not a async fn,  `await` is only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks.  how to fix it?
            //   match  reqwest::get(path).poll { bla bla }  ?
            
            reqwest::get(path); // this call will block 5s
            println!("this is a test : {}", self.name);
            task::current().notify();
            return Ok(Async::NotReady);
        }
    }
}


#[test]
fn test_pool() {
    let w = JnsWatcher::new("name1".to_string());
    let w2 = JnsWatcher::new("name2".to_string());

    let t = thread::Builder::new()
        .name("watchtest".to_string())
        .spawn(move || {
            current_thread::block_on_all(join_all(vec![w, w2])).unwrap();
        })
        .expect("fail to spawn worker thread");


    t.join().unwrap();
    println!("test end");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest create `Stream` instances using `futures::stream::iter_ok` and use `futures::stream::select_all` function to poll all the futures in the stream concurrently.

So the code might look like this.

```
    use std::thread;
    use std::thread::sleep;
    
    use futures::{Async, Future, Stream, task};
    use futures::future::join_all;
    use futures::stream::{iter_ok, select_all};
    use tokio::runtime::current_thread;
    
    pub struct JnsWatcher {
        name: String,
    }
    
    impl JnsWatcher {
        pub fn new(name: String) -> Self {
            JnsWatcher {
                name
            }
        }
    }
    
    impl Future for JnsWatcher {
        type Item = ();
        type Error = ();
    
        fn poll(&mut self) -> Result<Async<Self::Item>, Self::Error> {
            sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(5)); // simulate a long poll request
            println!("this is a test : {}", self.name);
            task::current().notify();
            Ok(Async::NotReady)
        }
    }
#[test]
fn test_pool() {
    let watchers = vec![
        JnsWatcher::new("name1".to_string()),
        JnsWatcher::new("name2".to_string()),
        JnsWatcher::new("name3".to_string()),
    ];

    let stream = select_all(watchers.into_iter().map(|w| w.into_future()));

    let t = thread::Builder::new()
        .name("watchtest".to_string())
        .spawn(move || {
            current_thread::block_on_all(stream).unwrap();
        })
        .expect("fail to spawn worker thread");

    t.join().unwrap();
    println!("test end");
}
```

Comment: I run the code and it output this is a test : namexxx every 5s, seems not work

Comment: It seems like the `JnsWatcher` future is not being polled properly. Here are a few things you can try:

1. Make sure that the `tokio::run` function is being called to drive the event loop. You can modify the `test_poll` function to use `tokio::run` instead of `tokio::spawn`:
2. Make sure that the `JnsWatcher` future is being polled repeatedly by the event loop. You can modify the poll function to check if it has already been polled during the current loop iteration, and if so, return `NotReady`:

Comment: I think with these changes, the `JnsWatcher` future should be polled repeatedly every 5 seconds, and the "this is a test : namexxx" message should be printed to the console at each poll interval.

Comment: but what I want is another future can be poll again without wating previous future which is block on a request.

Comment: In that case, I think you can use a combination of `tokio::spawn` and `tokio::task::yield_now`. `tokio::task::yield_now` is a function that suspends the current task and allows other tasks to run. You can use this to yield control back to the `Tokio` runtime so that other tasks can continue running while waiting for the long poll request to complete.

Comment: You can add those to JnsWatcher future.
`pub async fn run(&self) {
        loop {
            tokio::spawn(self.poll());
            yield_now().await;
        }
    }

    async fn poll(&self) {
        println!("starting long poll for {}", self.name);
        // Simulate a long poll request with sleep
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
        println!("finished long poll for {}", self.name);
    }`

Comment: but when the request is bloking ,  I can not use yield_now at that time. if I yield_now before blocking , the request will never be call, what i think is it right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If you call `yield_now` before the blocking request, the request will never be made. Instead, you can use a `TimerFuture` from the `tokio` crate to periodically check if a new request should be made, and then make the request if it should be.

Comment: and the real code is a long poll request, I must use a async request crate ?  I use a blocking future reqwest right now

Comment: Yes, if you have a long-polling request, you should use an async HTTP client to avoid blocking the thread. `reqwest` is a synchronous HTTP client, so it is not suitable for long-polling requests.

There are several async HTTP clients available in Rust, such as `hyper`, `surf`, and `reqwest` also has an async version called `reqwest::async_`. You can choose the one that fits your needs and integrate it into your code.

Comment: new problem,  if use an async client,  the code will be like this : 
 reqwest::get(path).await;   but in the poll fn, rust complier  complains`await` is only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks [E0728] .

Comment: Yes. `await` can only be used within an `async` block or function. One solution is to use a different crate that supports asynchronous HTTP requests, such as `surf` or `hyper`.

Comment: how to use surf or hyper,  their demo is also : client.get(uri).await?;    but i want is match client.get(uri).poll { bla bla } ?

Comment: If you are looking for a demo, you can check their github example link. You can see how to use `surf` and `hyper` together here.  https://hyperspace-project.org/docs/examples/surf/